How to configure SSO page with Microsoft so it does auth without user input and redirects to next page
I would like to use Microsoft SSO for corporate customers to authenticate to my web app. But some companies don't want to need their users to click on the Microsoft page where they confirm they want to log in.
How can I configure SSO (Saml or OpenId or whatever) so when I redirect users to the microsoft page it will auto-redirect back to my website with appropriate auth info. Obviously this assumes they're already logged in and only with one userid, but that will be the case most of the time.

For OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect (OIDC), you can simply add prompt=none as a parameter to your authentication request to attempt a silent login using SSO.
For example: (Taken directly from Microsoft Documentation here.)
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&prompt=none

Note, that if you enable prompt=none, and the request can't be completed silently, the identity platform will return an error which you'll have to handle, and request a login using, for example, prompt=login.
